# How to round multiple faces in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, subdivision-surface

is there a way like in the subdivide window in Edit Mode to round faces? I want a round arm.

[image: square arm]

The feature in the subdivide pane is **Smoothness**
[image: Smoothness in subdivide Pane]

Comment: Have you tried Smooth Vertices?

Comment: Select the edges round the arm and right-click > Loop Tools > Circle. You'll need the LoopTools addon enabled in Preferences > addons to do that.

Comment: @Carlo this is for shading. I want to manipulate the verticies. But thanks for the tip. Maybe i could use it somewhere else

Comment: @JohnEason this solved the Problem for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good! I'd have posted it as an answer with images myself if I hadn't had to go out shopping! :^)

Comment: there are two command called Smooth Vertices, I'm obiuvsly refferring to the one not related to shading, but to actual geometry. You can find ot under the Vertex menu.

Answer (score 1):

@JohnEason pointed it out. With the Looptool Addons it is possible.

- enable Loop Tool Plugin in User preferences
- Select faces
- use Circle ub the editor tab
  [image: Circle]